# how to customize log files?

Tags: linux, wtmp

As you know better than me any action in linux store in log files, like `/var/log`, I was wondering is there anyway to customize the log file in linux, for example in this case I'm the root of my system, and I don't want to log root's actions, but the others are important because I want to monitor them.

in this case just `wtmp` is important to me !